# Rails & Devise - Getting double notices on login and logout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

In the application.html.erb I added the following code right above the yield statement:

```
<p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
```

Whenever an action for login or logout is performed two repeated notices show on screen. (Rest of the code its pretty standard configuration from devise instructions)

[Two notifications image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYOrH.png)

Strangely enough if I comment out "notice" in the application file its all fine and dandy. But if i only comment out "alert" i get double notifications again. What is the issue?

Comment: You must have a second <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p> somewhere

Comment: How are`notice` and `alert` defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases if you scaffolded your models and controllers, there is duplicated code in your views.

```
<p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
```

Check out your views in `app/views/` and see if there is duplicate code.

Comment: Wow, i see that I lacked to mention that i did indeed scaffolded controllers. I removed the code you pointed out from my application.html.erb (even though its mentioned in devise). Its probably not needed to add the "notice" and "alert" code on the application file when doing scaffolded controllers. Thank you @nikola-Đuza. Im free of this issue thanks to your suggestion.

Comment: Additionally on views,  in one of the scaffolds that i created, on the index.html.erb i deleted: <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

Comment: @Maikol88 glad you sorted it out :)